# How can I check in code the Android version like 1.5 or 1.6

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to check in code what Android release version is running currently on target device. Can you supply code example?

Answer (score 25):

I was looking for this and didn't find a solution - ended up here and I figured it out myself so for anyone out there looking for this:

`int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;`

this returns os sdk level 7 eclair 8 froyo etc

Comment: This is actually not really a correct answer to the question, as SDK_INT is available from API Level 4 (Donut, 1.6) on. So, it fails when trying to detect 1.5, which was part of the question...

Answer (score 9):

To get the build version of Android like: 2.2, 2.3.3, 4.0 or 4.0.3 ... **use the following code:**

```
String deviceVersion = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a duplicate of my own question: [ndk version at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441680/how-do-i-know-what-android-ndk-version-im-running-in).
Short answer: no easy way for a native application to do it (you could however run a Java app and communicate with it to get the version).

Answer (score 1):

can you execute `getprop ro.build.version.release` shell command on your device ?

Answer (score -2):

This works

also import the followng:

```
import com.android.phonetests.TEST_INTERFACE;
import android.os.Build;
import android.app.ActivityThread;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.IPackageManager;


private int GetSDKVersion()
{
    int version = 0;
    IPackageManager pm = ActivityThread.getPackageManager();
    try
    {
        //returns a ref to my application according to its application name
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.android.phonetests", 0);

        if (applicationInfo != null) 
        {           
            version = applicationInfo.targetSdkVersion; ////this makes the same -> version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
            Log.i(LOG_TAG,"[DBG] version: " + version);  

            //2 is 5
            //2.01 6 (Donut - 2.01)
            //2.2  7 (Eclair - 2.2) currently it is Eclair_MR1 (Major Release)                  
            switch (version) 
            {                           
                case Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1:
                Log.i(LOG_TAG,"[DBG] version: ECLAIR");//2.2  7 (Eclair - 2.2) currently it is Eclair_MR1 (Major Release)
                break;
                case Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT:
                Log.i(LOG_TAG,"[DBG] version: DONUT");//2.01 6 (Donut - 2.01)
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (android.os.RemoteException e){}      
    return version;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this wasn't working on my 2.1 Nexus One. "com.android.phonetests" seems to not exist.

Comment: Shouldn't you just be getting the value defined in Build.VERSION.SDK_INT instead of querying the targetSdkVersion from some random package?

Comment: thanks, 
don't know why I didn't use this from the beginning?
I simply went a difficult way :-(

Thanks
Ilana

Comment: Steve Pomeroy, I have used package name of my apk file => com.android.phonetests. Now any body who will use my code example should off coarse change it with his/her package name !!