# Android device version

Tags: android, android-emulator

How can i get the current android deveice version  (1.5, 1.6, 2.0, etc.) programmatically.
i.e I have installed my apk in ANdroid 2.2 device..
  I need to get the device version (android emulator version in which my application is currently running )

Comment: Already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at following post might help [How can I check in code the Android version like 1.5 or 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014117/how-can-i-check-in-code-the-android-version-like-1-5-or-1-6)

Comment: but my need is to get my target device 's OS version (15,2.1,2.2) in which my application is installed

Comment: the use following int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

Answer (score 10):

The integer representing the API level can be found at `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`

So you could do:

```
int apiLevel = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

The possible values of that integer across all devices can be found in [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html). If you want to compare versions against a named release of android, use the name of each constant here. You cannot compare the device version against the release numbers like 2.1 , 2.2 etc. so if you want to do that you must use the release name or API level, and then convert manually.

Comment: Keep in mind that android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is supported since API level 4 (1.6)